# CSS: text-align-last doesn't work in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm wondering if someone here has try to use text-align-last in HTML email. I have used this code and they're not working at all in HTML email :

```html
<p style="text-align:justify; text-align-last:center;">This is the long text you see. This is the long text you see. This is the long text you see.</p>
```

Already use -moz, -webkit, -ms, and it's still not working. I have searched the answers and still didn't find why it's not working. Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: html emails are very limited in what they can do - text-align-last seems to be experimental so you have no chance of it being supported!

Comment: This very much depends on what program/client is used to view the mail. In webmail interfaces or modern mail clients this should work – but for dinosaurs like f.e. Outlook, that still render HTML emails using an engine that is a decade old, there’s very little chance.

Comment: The best way to control text alignment in html email is to use table

Answer (score 1):

**`text-align-last` is [not widely supported in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).** It might work in Apple Mail and iOS Mail, but you're unlikely to get good coverage using `text-align-last`.

However `text-align` *is* supported everywhere. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there could be another way to achieve this type of text-alignment.

Comment: Writing HTML email is like going back in time. Outlook has a terribly primitive HTML rendering engine and that's not going away any time soon. [Thanks Microsoft](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook).